# App wont install from some devices on Android12

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

[image]I have a problem that at first android 12 wouldnt install the app from Google Play store because the

```
exported="false"
```

wasnt declared in the manifest for activities.

So I put the exported flag in only the Launcher activity and Broadcast Reciever and then it installed on my device and the emulators.

The problem is that some users are still reporting that they cannot install the app still from Google Play.

So what Im wondering is Do you have to set the

```
exported="false"
```

flag in every activity and broadcast reciever? because there are still a bunch of activities with no exported flag set, Could that be the problem? Maybe some devices are stricter with manifest

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.appboy.AppboyGcmReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                 />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `exported="true"`? Only if activity has an intent-filter.

Comment: @blackapps I updated the question, are you saying that exported has to be true if something has an intent filter?

Comment: Is there any specific error shown in Play Store when they are trying to install the app?

Comment: @SujalKumar I just updated the question with what is going on with a picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem was that the file provider was matching other app because there was an error in the build.gradle where it was being set. The applicationId was null for some reason making the file provider

null.fileProvider

Turns out, the McDonald's app has the same issue, if you have null.fileProvider and try to install the app with McDonald's already installed it won't install.

Posting this so others can see.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the launcher and / or the broadcast receiver to be visible to the OS and other apps, then you should set `exported=true`. Setting it to false will keep those components internal to your app.

You should be able to see where the problem lies in the merged manifest. If you open up the AndroidManifest in AndroidStudio you should see :

[image]

Click on that will show you the results of all the manifests after merging and it should highlight any issues.

[image]